# How to replace numbers in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

My database has a lot of descriptions which are similar to each other and I want to group them together, but because of different numbers, they are not being grouped together. So is there any way I can mask the numbers and make the descriptions same.

We can do that in Excel or Notepad++, using find and replace, so anyway in which it would be possible in SQL. I know we can replace in SQL using the function

```
REPLACE('column', 'new input', 'to be replaced')
```

But how to do it for regex, as the numbers can be in any combination.

I am using PostgreSQL.

Some inputs :-

```
sample input description 123
sample input description 456
this is another description 678
this is another description 999
```

I would like to convert them to:-

```
sample input description xxx
sample input description xxx
this is another description xxx
this is another description xxx
```

the numbers can be anywhere.

I am doing it on redshift.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: please decide on the vendor, also provide some samples

Comment: That's not *masking*. You want to transform the input based on some unspecified rules that will produce the same result from different input. What *are* those rules?

Comment: Postgresql supports regex contrary to sql-server. Regex .Net assembly can be accesed  from sql-server using CLR integration.

Comment: @Serg and neither should be used carelessly. A query that uses a regex can't use any underlying indexes. The server would have to cache the transformed data before grouping. It's even worse for filtering - the server would have to scan the entire table *and* consume the entire text value each time before determining whether there's a match or not. This can waste a lot of memory if there are many rows and/or the text field is large

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd use

```
regexp_replace(col, '[[:digit:]]+', '#')
```

in order to replace any number of digits with a single #.

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/BFSP36237

Use the flag 'g' if multiple numbers can occur in a string:

```
regexp_replace(col, '[[:digit:]]+', '#', 'g')
```

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WHTJ51233

Answer (score 2):

You can use this REGEXP_REPLACE  function in below format.

```
select regexp_replace ( columnthatneedtomask,'[0-9]','x' )  from table ;
```

refer below link for more information:-

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_REPLACE.html

Answer (score 2):

```
select regexp_replace(column, '[0-9]', 'x', 'g') as newcolumn from table;
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide some explanations, maybe a link to documentation. And why `from table`?